# x264 on Ubuntu video bad/corrupted

Tags: ubuntu, x264

I am trying to use command line `x264` to produce a blu-ray compatible file for use in Adobe Encore.  For the source file I've tried both ProRes and mpeg2, both **1080p24**.  Both files import into Encore fine (no transcoding needed which is great) but the ProRes version is pink and grey "static" and the mpeg2 is just a bunch of green/black lines. The exact same files and the exact same commands on my Win7 PC come out fine.  I'm only doing a 10 sec sample of the complete 90min movie. I'd love for it to work on Ubuntu cause it is running a new i7 **haswell** that encodes much quicker than my PC (many hours difference in encoding time)

```
Ubuntu 13.04

x264 0.135.2 f0c1c53<br>
built on Jul 24 2013, gcc: 4.7.3<br>
configuration: --bit-depth=8 --chroma-format=all<br>
x264 license: GPL version 2 or later

command:
    x264 --bitrate 30000 --preset veryslow --tune film --bluray-compat --fps 24000/1001 --force-cfr --bframes 3 --ref 4 --muxer raw --no-weightb --weightp 0 --b-pyramid none --vbv-maxrate 40000 --vbv-bufsize 30000 --level 4.1 --profile high --keyint 24 --min-keyint 1 --open-gop --slices 4 --colorprim "bt709" --transfer "bt709" --colormatrix "bt709" --sar 1:1  -o output.264 --input-res 1920x1080 sample.mov
```

(if it would work I'd be doing two pass encoding)

I am able to encode the sample file with ffmpeg to h264 (if that helps).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you most probably have problems with decoding of your input source and not with encoding itself. Make sure that you use lavf demuxing and not fallback to raw input (it is bad idea to use --input-res if your input is not raw yuv). You can use "--demuxer lavf" to make sure you use it. Also with ProRes you may need new enough libav/ffmpeg used for lavf input (iirc its support is not so good in old libav/ffmpeg).

P.S. btw. Such questions are offtopic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought as well which is why I tried the mpeg2 file instead of ProRes and why I tried encoding the ProRes with ffmpeg to a mp4 which uses libx264 by default (and that worked).  I get unknown demuxer when I try your suggestion.  If I do not use --input-res I get an error about the width not being divisible by two.  Even though ffmpeg reads it as being 1920x1080